# I can't Connect navigation drawer items with there related activities and fregmant

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have made a navigation drawer in my app , but I have a problem that I can't open any activity related to any menu item in navigation drawer .

for example in this code I am trying to only display a toast message ,also there is no response when I click on the item from the menu.
[image]

Comment: I would recommend that you add code as text and not as image

Comment: Also add more information regarding how you setup the view, your xml and nav menus etc. This is very less information to determine anything

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using menu items and I would suggest giving the same id for the navigation destination and its corresponding item. 
if items id is nav_home then destionation id should also be nav_home in navigation.xml

```
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
                R.id.nav_home, {*other navigations*}), binding.drawerLayout)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        binding.navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

when you set it like this it will automatically connect the destination to items and u dont have to set the onclick manually